kernel lost after running pycaret
I am working on SSH network provided by my company there are some limit.
I was using jupyternotebook extension from vscode. It works fine but for some reason after I run pycaret create_model or other function that involve create_model like compared_model in jupyter notebook, the cell after that just doesnt produce any output like kernel is lost.
so I try:
%run -i test_pycaret.py

with test_pycaret.py a very simple script that call get_data and create_model. The catch is the script run to finish, meaning I get all the output .csv or whatever output of the test_pycaret.py and notebook ui show that the process is done. But whatever cell I am running next to that in notebook cant run and have to select the kernel again. the same thing would happen if i migrate all the code in test_pycaret.py to jupyter.
I try to reinstall the jupyter notebook extension.
I also try to reinstall the .venv including pycaret but same problem happen so I thought it has something to do with jupyternotebook mostly.
This had never happen until now when I tried pycaret

Can you check if this is reproducible in the browser (or VS Code only)?
